# Is there CiviContribute API documentation?

Tags: civicontribute

I'm wondering which CiviContribute API calls are required to make a donation happen. For example, I'm assuming that I don't need to make any calls to PayPal or Stripe, because the CiviContribute API will do this under the hood.

I'm using the REST api, but probably general CiviContribute API documentation would suffice.

Is there any documentation of the process for making a donation with the API, and which calls are needed in a typical scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you want to achieve exactly, but the API that I use is called Contribution. It creates a contribution in CiviCRM but it does not automatically make calls to PayPal or Stripe.

And I am glad it does not because most NGO's in my corner of the world (Northern Europe) hardly use PayPal and have never heard of Stripe. They want all their payments processed with SEPA, which probably you never heard of.

Documentation on the API can be found here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/

Comment: I see, but I think I should not be implementing actual transactions if the CiviCRM API provides this (even though afaict it's not explicitly documented how to use it).

Comment: You could ask here how you should do this, I am sure there are lots of Stripe-experienced community members that are happy to help you. But you would need to change the title of your question and be more specific.

Comment: Afaict your answer is correct, I will mark it as the accepted answer. There is no API documentation, but you can figure some things out via the API Explorer.